# some funky redirecting on Drupal server

Tags: redirect, drupal

I have a drupal instance on a linux server located at

```
var/www/html
```

I created a indepent html file called index.html in the following directory

```
var/www/html/special_project/index.html
```

I am able to see "special_project/index.html" by typing

```
mysite/special_project/index.html
```

I want to include some javascript files located in special_project/script,

example:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script/my_script.js'></script>
```

however at this point the server has some rewite rule, loads the Drupal bootstrap and throws back a page not found error for the javascript.

Is there something I can put in .htaccess file to indicate to the server to prevent this behaviour?

**EDIT**

This is what virtual hosts looks like now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName intranet.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

If I modified the following as Shane suggested, should it do the trick?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Alias /special_project /var/www/html/special_project

    <Directory /var/www/html/special_project>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ServerName intranet.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal's default `.htaccess` is a beast, I'd recommend avoiding the issue; use an `Alias` directive to load the non-Drupal content from outside of the Drupal docroot.

```
Alias /special-project /var/www/static/special-project
<Directory /var/www/static/special-project>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This needs to be configured in the Apache configuration, not an `.htaccess` file, so it won't work if you don't have access to that.

Comment: I added additional config info above. Can I mix virtual host and directory attributes together like this?

Comment: @ethanallan The `Alias` and `<Directory>` will work outside of the `<VirtualHost>`, but the best approach would be to put them inside of it, to avoid having the configuration apply to any other virtual hosts accidentally.

Comment: made the change as suggested . restarted the server. updated my question above to reflect my canges.... however same error as before. :(

Comment: So the js file is located at `/var/www/static/special-project/script/my_script.js`, correct?  And the client browser sends a request to `http://intranet.mysite.com/special_project/script/myscript.js` and gets a 404?

Comment: OK. now working. silly syntax error! Thanks 100X

Comment: @ethanallan Great, glad to hear it!